# React SPA with initial state/route, served from Django

Tags: python, django, reactjs, single-page-application, server-side-rendering

I am facing an unusual use-case with React and Django. My process starts with a POST request initiated by an app running on user's system to my Django server(The response is displayed on the browser). The POST request contains the data required for authenticating the user. Once authenticated, the server returns a simple HTML page customized for that user, including the details necessary to authenticate subsequent requests(like form submissions). Now I need to replace that simple HTML page with a react application. The problem is how can I embed the user specific info into the react app when returning the react app from server, so that I don't have to ask user to provide authentication information again once application loads on browser. Is this even possible while using react?

Answer (score 0):

Considering that you returns properties of user from server side, you could use React to render the components into the page conditionally, based on the properties that was received from server side.